# Transform dataframe into dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to transform dataframe into dictionary of key and list of values.
The index probe_fk to be the key and box_fk to be values.

```
             product_fk   vp_fk         box_fk
probe_fk                                   
'83348'            101    326            8548
'83348'            101    326            8549
'83348'            101    326            8550
'83348'            101    326            8551
'105513'           107    357            8866
'105513'           107    357            8864
'111996'           107    365            9059
```

I want final result be like:

```
{'83348':[8548, 8549, 8550,8551],
'105513':[8866, 8864],
'111996':[9059]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
In [95]: df.groupby(level=0)['box_fk'].apply(list).to_dict()
Out[95]: {'105513': [8866, 8864], '111996': [9059], '83348': [8548, 8549, 8550, 8551]}
```